# Why these 2 codes don't give similar output?

Tags: arrays, c, array-difference, array-initialization

The difference is in 4th line for both code(given below).
In 1st one, I declared some variable and then initialized the array.
In 2nd one, I initialized the array first and then declared the variables.
Here's the sample output for input: `55 6`.

```
1st code : 1       55      3       5       7       9       8       6       4       2

2nd code : 1       3       5       7       9       55      6       4       2       9
```

2nd one is correct btw.
And in 1st code the new number is always in 2nd position.

Code 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, num, pos, a[9] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2 };
    scanf("%d", &num);
    scanf("%d", &pos);
    for (i = 9; i >= pos; i--)
    {
        a[i] = a[i - 1];
    }
    a[pos - 1] = num;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[9] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2 }, i, num, pos;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    scanf("%d", &pos);
    for (i = 9; i >= pos; i--)
    {
        a[i] = a[i - 1];
    }
    a[pos - 1] = num;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` stores 9 elements, therefore the indices are `[0..8]`. In both loops you access `a[9]` which is an element out of the bounds of your array and therefore invoking UB (undefined behavior).

Comment: `printf("%d\t",a[i]);` when `i == 9` is out of bounds so the program has undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416792/509868)

Comment: `i < 10` should be `i < 9` in both programs.

Comment: And `i=9` should be `i=8`.

Comment: Depending on the order of your variable declarations, writing out of bounds causes different problems.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say the second code is correct. It prints 10 numbers from an array with only 9 numbers. The correct output should be `1 3 5 7 9 55 8 6 4`.

Comment: The problem of undefined behavior is solved (thanks) but I need 10 outputs. How can I get it ?

Comment: @RahulDas Re: _"but I need 10 outputs. How can I get it ?"_ - Make an array of `int[10]` instead of `int[9]`. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/PqEP3j3qn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both codes have undefined behavior in this loop:

```
    for (i = 9; i >= pos; i--)
    {
        a[i] = a[i - 1];
    }
```

It is incorrect because the first iteration, assuming `pos <= 9`, will write to `a[9]` which is beyond the end of the array of length `9`.  The last valid index in this array is `8`.  There is a similar problem in the last loop where you iterate until `i < 10`, reading beyond the array boundary.

The effect of undefined behavior is unpredictable: the program may behave as expected as does code #2 or produce surprising results as does code #1.

The likely explanation in your case is the last value in the array `2` is written beyond the end of the array `a`, exactly in the memory location set aside by the compiler for the variable `pos`. So `pos` becomes `2` and the value `55` is inserted at the second position.  This may explain what you observe, but it is only coincidental: the compiler could allocate the variables in a different order or not even in memory, so this undefined behavior could have other side effects, including a program crash. Nothing can be expected.

Small, seemingly innocuous changes in the source causing surprising changes in the program behavior is a good indication of undefined behavior in play somewhere in the code.

To preserve all 9 numbers and insert the new value, you should define the array with a length of 10.

Furthermore, it is confusing to have `pos` be `1` based.  You should perform sanitary checks on the value input and adjust `pos` before the loop to compare apples to apples.

Also check the return values of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid or missing input.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
#define LEN 10
    int a[LEN] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0 };
    int i, num, pos;

    if (scanf("%d %d", &num, &pos) != 2) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (pos >= 1 && pos <= LEN) {
        pos -= 1;    // adjust pos as an index into a
        for (i = LEN; i-- > pos;) {
            a[i] = a[i - 1];
        }
        a[pos] = num;
    } else {
        // pos outside the array boundaries
        // produce an error message or do not change the array
    }
    for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```